# Spring MVC app Images storage

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Spring MVC App with AngularJS For front-end, deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I was storing an Images by creating a directory within the app
**ex:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload_image", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("filename") String filename){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String orgName =file.getOriginalFilename();
                String filePath =  "img_temp";
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + orgName);

                //Format check
                if(!IsImage(serverFile)) {return new JsonResponse("FAIL","Is not an image: "+orgName);}

                //Upload
                try {
                    file.transferTo(serverFile);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new JsonResponse("FAIL","File uploaded failed: "+orgName);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new JsonResponse("FAIL","File uploaded failed: "+orgName);
                }

                //Success
                return new JsonResponse("OK","");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new JsonResponse("FAIL","File uploaded failed: "+file.getName() + " => " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse("FAIL","File uploaded failed: "+ file.getName() + " because the file was empty.");
        }
    }
```

The application is some kind of classified ads.
There are 2 main usage for images storage: images for items (publicly available) and images for temp items (not public, but also don't need any special security)

**Problem:**
It is become clear that this image storage way is very unstable.
First problem - each time i deploy the .war file of my app, i have to backup images folders manually and then copy to deployed app.
Today, it happened that because of high load, the elastic beanstalk instance was terminated and new is created. All the images lost. So, definitely have to deal with it.

**Question:**

What is the beast way to handle images storage?

I was thinking about Amazon S3. But then the problem is - it will be hard to debug because all the code will be based on interactions with local AWS environment, so i can't debug it on my local machine. Any solution for this maybe? S3 seems as a good option if not this.

**Other small sub-question:**
For now, this is the algorithm how images are uploaded:
On posting form, there is a button to choose an image. once image is selected it is sent to `/upload_image` controller and uploaded into the temp folder. Then, once the user submit a final request, the image moved from `img_temp` to `images/*created_item_id*` **Is it a right way to handle this process?**

Comment: When you use S3 why will be it hard to debug? I did not get what issue will you face?

Comment: that i can't debug it on my local machine

Comment: Yes, you can debug it on your local machine.  You have to add the AWS SDK to your project, create a class that will handle the uploading of images to AWS S3.  The said class is the one you're gonna debug.

Comment: Ok maybe i misunderstood something from my 1st look on how it works.

What is about my "sub-question"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your use case you definitely should integrate AWS S3 so that you are covered for the disasters the one happened with you.

> What is the beast way to handle images storage?
>
> I was thinking about Amazon S3. But then the problem is - it will be
>   hard to debug because all the code will be based on interactions with
>   local AWS environment, so i can't debug it on my local machine. Any
>   solution for this maybe? S3 seems as a good option if not this.

For this if you implement S3 along with AWS SDK your debugging issue will go.

> Other small sub-question: For now, this is the algorithm how images
>   are uploaded: On posting form, there is a button to choose an image.
>   once image is selected it is sent to /upload_image controller and
>   uploaded into the temp folder. Then, once the user submit a final
>   request, the image moved from img_temp to images/*created_item_id* Is
>   it a right way to handle this process?

This process seems fine but one more additional change you can do is start a cron job which will copy images in this path `images/*created_item_id*` to S3 bucket so that you have backup of the images.